# vector operations between a two-dimensional and a three-dimensional vectors

Tags: calculus

If you have a two-dimensional and a three-dimensional vectors, are vector operations (like dot product, cross product, addition, etc) defined between these two vectors? I though that since two-dimensional vectors can be written as three dimensional vectors with third component being zero, this is possible.

Comment: If you write  vectors as   $2i-4j+3k$, it even comes naturally to do exactly that. A two-dimensional vector looks just like a 3d vector with the last component zero.

Answer (score 1):

Depends how nitpicky you want to be. If you can embed the two-dimensional vector into a subspace of the three-dimensional space, then of course there is a natural way to extend it. Depends on what you want to do!